# Qual a diferença entre executar SQL SGBD e em uma linguagem intermediária(PHP, Java, C#)?

Tags: php

Olá, preciso de uma informação preciosa que não sei justificar poderiam me ajudar no seguinte cenário?

**PHP:**
Ao executar a instrução SQL(UPDATE) pelo PHP e ao retornar na lista dos produtos que acabo de atualizar e clicar novamente no mesmo produto fica com o valor antigo exemplo: DESATIVADO, se eu retornar novamente a lista o produto é mostrado como ativo.(sendo atualizado após uma segunda vez);

**T-SQL:**
Já se eu estiver na tela e executar o UPDATE diretamente pelo SGBD, e voltar para a lista de produtos e clicar novamente no produto mostrará que está ATIVO, conforme o que desejo.

**Observação a lista:** A lista de produtos e a tela do produto estão em um Iframe e não armazenam cache também.

Abraços,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o que estava ocorrendo era que após eu dar um UPDATE no PHP, existia um ultimo update logo após, sendo o do sistema o último. Ou seja sobrescrevendo o meu.